# Happy 6 month-aversary!

Tags: discussion

Retrocomputing hit 6 months old today, congratulations to everyone who continues to participate.  Here's to doubling our activity before we hit 1 year old!

Today also marks the first day users can earn the Excavator badge on [main](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/excavator) and [meta](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/excavator).  Figured I'd give any badge collectors a heads up.